# Rails & Active Record: Find objects whose children don't belong to current_user OR who don't have any children

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

User.rb

```
 has_many :votes
```

Event.rb

```
  has_many :votes
```

Vote.rb

```
 belongs_to :user
 belongs_to :event
```

I am trying to render all the Events that the current_user has not voted on.

Consider this situation:

- There are 100 events `Event.includes(:votes).count  ==> 100`
- The User has voted on 5 events `current_user.votes.count ==> 5`
- There are 75 events with at least one vote from other users
- 20 of the events have not received votes from *any* users

The result I'm looking for should render the 95 events that have not been voted on by the current_user, including events that have not been voted on by *any* user.

This query gets all the events that NO users have voted on:

```
Event.includes(:votes).where(:votes => {:id => nil}).references(:votes).count ==> 20
```

What query can I use to get all the events that have been voted on by users *excluding* those that have been voted on by current user (should return 75 in the example above)? I tried the below query but it returned 80 (it *included* events voted on by the current_user):

```
Event.includes(:votes).where.not(:votes => {:id => current_user}).references(:votes).count ==> 80
```

1. What query can I use to get events with votes, excluding ones that current user voted for
2. Can I combine the two queries into one?

Comment: Check the answer if it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Hacky but fun answer

```
class Event
  has_many :votes
  has_many :user_votes,
             ->() { where({user_id: Thread.current[:user]&.id}.compact) },
             class_name: 'Vote'

  def self.using_user(user)
    old_user, Thread.current[:user] = Thread.current[:user], user
    yeild
  ensure
    Thread.current[:user] = old_user
  end
end

Event.using_user(current_user) do
  Event.includes(:user_votes).where("votes.id IS NULL")
end
```

#### Original answer:

```
Event.
  joins(
   "LEFT OUTER JOIN votes ON votes.event_id = events.id AND " +
   "votes.user_id = #{user.id}"
  ).
  where("votes.id IS NULL")
```

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I needed. Thanks so much... btw, is there an ActiveRecord way to do this?

Comment: There is no elegant way to do this in Rails. I have suggested an approach take a look.

Answer (score 1):

**Can I combine the two queries into one?**

Use [merge](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/SpawnMethods.html#method-i-merge) if you want to combine using AND:

```
results = frecords.merge(lrecords)
```

If you want to combine using OR, use or (only available in ActiveRecord 5+):

```
results = frecords.or(lrecords)
```

Answer (score 0):

> 1. What query can I use to get events with votes, excluding ones that current user voted for.

```
events_current_user_voted_on = current_user.votes.pluck(:event_id) 
events_all_users_voted_on = Vote.pluck(:event_id).uniq

events_only_others_voted_on = events_all_users_voted_on - events_current_user_voted_on

# 75 events with at least one vote from other users
Event.where(id: events_only_others_voted_on)
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer for your first question:
I have modified your tried query a little bit so try this

```
Event.includes(:votes).where.not(:votes => {:user_id => current_user}).references(:votes).count
```

notice the where condition. You need to check `user_id` column of `votes`
or you can try string syntax like:

```
Event.includes(:votes).where.not("votes.user_id" => current_user).references(:votes).count
```

about your second question, I am not sure I understand your requirement. If you need to filter events with at least 1 vote and from other user only then just add another to `where` statement .

```
Event.includes(:votes).where.not("votes.user_id" => current_user, "votes.user_id" => nil).references(:votes).count
```

And BTW, I think you have a error in `vote.rb` you have specified a association to itself instead of association to `Event` i.e `belongs_to :event`